# Crashes after parsing the equation

Tags: c++11, exprtk

The application want to parse a string equation to mathematics and return the data to user. for this purpose the library is used is [exprtk](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html)

for easy analysis I have shared minimum working code
[minimum working code](https://pastebin.com/tQiyxJKf)

when application parses the string to code back to back [**multithreaded but locked**]

```
void reset()
{
      // Why? because msvc doesn't support swap properly.
      //stack_ = std::stack<std::pair<char,std::size_t> >();
      /**
      it was crashing on destructor on ~deque()
      stating memory reallocation
      so I change it to pop so for now this has been resolved
      */
      while(stack_.size()) stack_.pop();
      state_ = true;
      error_token_.clear();
}
```

now the code always crashes on

```
static inline void destroy(control_block*& cntrl_blck)
{
   if (cntrl_blck)
    {
        /**now crashes on this condition check*/
        if ( (0 !=   cntrl_blck->ref_count) &&  (0 == --cntrl_blck->ref_count) )
        {
           delete cntrl_blck;
        }

          cntrl_blck = 0;
     }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
pastebin code [updated new code with main](https://pastebin.com/zNpL70jM) has been added with main and minimum working code.
all the `shared_ptr` has been removed. now they are normal objects.
as for exprtk reset function has been changed to original one

```
void reset()
{
     // Why? because msvc doesn't support swap properly.
     stack_ = std::stack<std::pair<char,std::size_t> >();
     state_ = true;
     error_token_.clear();
}
```

and backtrace of gdb has been added [backtrace](https://pastebin.com/4ZrbW7sk)

Comment: Where in *your* code does the crash happen? Can you please create a [mcve] that replicates the problem, and show it to us? And if you haven't done it yet, then please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Code provided is not runnable, needs a `main` function etc. And ideally use `std::mutex` etc. not pthreads (especially after mentioning MSVC. also unique_lock/scoped_lock etc. avoids manual resource management). I would guess it is a memory error where something got deleted.

There is a lot of `shared_ptr` that seems to just be adding complexity/confusion. If it can be a stack/automatic variable, do that. If it can be `unique_ptr` do that. The piece of code in the question is not in the paste bin... But I would definitely avoid the manual `delete cntrl_blck` if any smart ptr can work.

Comment: @FireLancer I would say that the `destroy` function shown in the question is from a library, and not part of the actual code written by the OP. As is the `reset` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good call, can confirm `destroy` is in exprtk.hpp but seems to be re-formatted so a simple search didn't find it. I think OP modified the `reset`, code on github  assigns a fresh object as commented out.

Comment: @FireLancer both `reset` and `destroy` are library function.
as for mutex . I am running in unix environment with gcc4.9

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude minimal code is shared

Comment: I had to change some code. printf `%s` doesn't take a `std::string` or `double`, `get_value` didn't exist so used `value`, and syntax error around `for_each`. Compiled and no crash on my GCC 7.4 with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Fire Lancer standalone project is working for me also. But as soon as I merge in main project. It started crashes. Not a thing has been modified in standalone project. After seeing backtrace only thing I understood is its memory problems.

Comment: Maybe try with Valgrind if it picks up any memory error.